# Convert color image to black and white in Base64 format ( typescript )

Tags: typescript, canvas

I'm trying to turn a color image into black and white. I googled and came up with some code in JavaScript and converted it to TypeScript. But the code does not return all the photos and part of the photo becomes black and white.

For example, I receive the following input and output:

[image: InPut]

[image: OutPut]

My code is like this:

```
GrayScale() {
    const www = this;
    const myimage = new Image();
    myimage.src = this.croppedImage.src;
    myimage.onload = function () {
        const cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
        const cnx = cnv.getContext('2d');
        cnx.drawImage(myimage, 0, 0);
        const width = myimage.width;
        const height = myimage.height;
        const imgPixels = cnx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

        for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                const i = (y * 4) * width + x * 4;
                const avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
                imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
                imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
            }
        }

        cnx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
        www.croppedImage.src = cnx.canvas.toDataURL();
    };
}
```

Does anyone know what the reason is ? Thank you for your help

Comment: Your title suggests you want to convert an image to black and white (greyscale), but your pictures and code suggest you are already doing that. So what is the problem?

Comment: Output image is cropped because you need to set canvas's width and height to be equal to image size. `cnv.width = myimage.width; cnv.height = myimage.height;`. Do this before drawing on canvas. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: The problem is that the black and white photo is not the full size of the original photo. Part of it has turned black and white.

Comment: Arty OneSoul -  No, it did not solve the problem. The image got bigger but the same part of the photo was still black and white and the rest was white.

Comment: Then your issue is that the image is being cropped and has nothing to do with the part of your code that converts the image to greyscale. It begs the question, then, why you have an object named `croppedImage` in your code, since that's probably where the "problem" is.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with that part. This is a method of a module. One thing you do not pay attention to is that I passed the croppedImage of myself to this part. I posted the original photo. The problem is when the whole photo should be black and white

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul - Oh sorry. Your solution worked. I put your code in the wrong place. thank you

Comment: I'll post my comment then as answer so that question is answered.

Comment: @mahdiaghasi You posted an image that is a cropped portion of the original image, and the entire cropped image is successfully converted to greyscale. If only part of the image is being converted, that would mean the entire image was being rendered correctly but only a part of it was being converted. If that's the issue, post the entire image. But the solution posted by Arty suggests that I am right - your issue has nothing to do with the greyscale conversion and everything to do with your output image being cropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating canvas you need to set its width and height. Otherwise it gets some default size not equal to image size, and resulting image is cropped. I.e.:

```
cnv.width = myimage.width;
cnv.height = myimage.height;
```